# Is it better to declare variables to access nested properties of objects in for loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, for-loop, variables

```
// for example I have an object like this
const requestBody = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: {
            d: {
                e: 3,
                f: 4,
                g: {
                       h: {
                           i: 5,
                           j: {
                              k: 6
                           }
                       }
                   }
            }
        }
    }
]
// in for loop
for (let i = 0; i < requestBody.length; i++) {
     const g = requestBody[i].c.d.g;
     // do something related to g
     const k = g.h.j;
     // do something related to k
}
```

So, What I want to know here is according performance, is it better to declare variables and store nested properties and then access by variables in loops? or is it better to access nested properties of objects directly like requestBody[i].c.d.g and do someting related to g?

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you please let me know which way is better for millions of items? Though we are not dealing with millions of items, I just want to know.

Comment: @JaromandaX Got your points, thanks

Comment: This is referred to as **premature performance optimization**.  Such questions should only be studied and answered when there is a known and very specific and priority performance problem.  Then, you can benchmark possible solutions in all the relevant environments and decide which to use.  In an interpreted language with multiple run-time implementations, there is NO generic answer to a question like this.  And, doing anything that complicates the code at all is not appropriate unless you have a proven performance problem that justifies benchmarking different possible solutions.

Comment: And, an answer like this for a specific JS engine can even change with time as JS engines add different optimizations.  In fact, with the kinds of loop optimizations that can be implemented, messing with stuff inside the loop with temp variables can even sometimes ruin optimization paths.

Answer (score 1):

The way you nested properties to access variable elements, it's totally based on your real use case.

Because in JSON files, we are doing this only but it's totally based on your requirement and your data. You can't do nested every time, many times you have to optimize it to access a single element.

So try to think of this with a real use case and real data then only you can find out.

Otherwise, it's totally fine. But using a loop and accessing the elements it's not perhaps the right way, the best way to access these elements one by one is via serialize and deserialize.

That's just my thinking based on my experience, others can give their opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of time performance, it would generally be better to declare and cache your variable outside of your loop, especially if you are going to be accessing the nested property value several times.

This is discussed more in-depth in the O'Reilly book, "High Performance JavaScript" by Nicholas Zakas in chapter 2 and 3 where he discusses "accessing members"

You can also run a test here to see the performance of data access when object property depth varies: https://humanwhocodes.com/experiments/javascript/performance/data-access.html

Under the hood, a Javascript object is an associative array and each engine that executes JS has it's own way of accessing object properties. The V8 engine for example uses maps and hidden classes. They all have to adhere by ECMA standards so the performance concerns in those regards don't lie on the developer building upon the engine, they lie on the engines. However if we take your example above, if even one of those properties in your path is a getter, then everything to the right of that property would have to be regathered. You'll find that most browsers under the hoods, will cache your returned object value, for future ease of access.

You can find out more about JavaScript and how it handles properties here: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties

Comment: While this question is about objects, I wanted to add that this holds mostly true for array properties, but not always - Firefox has actually done some really amazing things to optimize array indexing, that actually makes their performance with array items better than with variables! Pretty impressive. However, this isn't the norm and the limitations you'll be facing with other browsers and devices generally means that you should still stick to literals and variables in order to optimize your performance. But I just wanted to share that one scenario.